# Sencha Touch: How to center align two buttons in bottom docked toolbar?

Tags: javascript, mobile, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I was wondering how I would be able to center align two buttons in a bottom docked toolbar.  The only attribute that addresses this on the buttosn I saw was `centered` but that centers them absolutely overlapping the buttons, is there a way to group them in the center?

Here is some code I have been working with:  http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xTZZg#k24Ni

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'SenchaFiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var panelNewForm = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            id: 'panelNewForm',
            title: 'TEST',
            html: 'TEST',
            pack: 'center',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom',
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'center'
                },
                items: [{
                    ui: 'decline',
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: function () {

                    }
                }, {
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: function () {

                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(panelNewForm);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can give your `toolbar` a [**layout**](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Toolbar-cfg-layout) config:

```
layout: {
    pack: 'center',
    type: 'hbox'
}
```

This will render your items in center of this toolbar horizontally.

Comment: Here is a fiddle I made with those suggestions:  http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xTZZg#k24Ni  Still not centering

Comment: you need to use `pack: center` not `align: center`. Demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#xTZZg#k24Ni#2eQ9J

Answer (score 0):

You can also make those center by using **xtype:'spacer'**. The Ext.Spacer component is generally used to put space between items in Ext.Toolbar components. Plz refer [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Spacer)

Now, here is your code sample :

```
 items: [{
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom',                
                items: [{
                    xtype:'spacer'
                },
                {
                    ui: 'decline',
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: function () {

                    }
                }, {
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    text: 'Save',
                    handler: function () {

                    }
                },{
                    xtype:'spacer'
                }]
            }]
```

Note: You can also adjust its centeredness by giving various [flex](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.Spacer-cfg-flex)